# Adding dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a javascript code of textboxes adding dynamically depending on how many items the client purchased and the item total amount each. The amounts are multiplied per quantity. What I can't do is to add them all in all. How do I achieve it? I used a while loop but it just returned the last item total. I know the logic, I just don't know how to save the total amount per item and then add it to the next one. Hope someone could help. Thanks.

```
function totalBillItem(rowcount){
   var quantity = parseFloat($("#quantity"+rowcount).val());
   var payment_interval = parseFloat($("#payment_interval").val());
   var billing_price = parseFloat($("#billing_price"+rowcount).val());
   var product = (quantity * billing_price).toFixed(2);

   $("#total"+rowcount).val(product);

   while(rowcount != 0) {
      var sub_total = parseFloat($("#total"+rowcount).val());
      rowcount--; 
   }

   var grand_total = sub_total; 
      $("#grand_total").val(grand_total);
   }
```

My HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;background-color:#89CFF0;">Name</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;background-color:#89CFF0;">Product Price</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;background-color:#89CFF0;">Quantity</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;background-color:#89CFF0;">Billing Price</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;background-color:#89CFF0;">Total</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $row_count=0;
    $offset=0;
    foreach( $data as $row ) :

    $dta = unserialize($row->userdata);
?>
<tr class="info">
    <td style="text-align:center;" id="prod_name<? echo $row_count; ?>"><?php echo $dta['product_name']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;" id="product_amount<? echo $row_count; ?>"><?php echo $dta['product_amount']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="quantity<? echo $row_count; ?>" id="quantity<? echo $row_count; ?>" class="span2" onkeydown="totalBillItem('<?php echo $row_count; ?>')" onkeyup="totalBillItem('<?php echo $row_count; ?>')" value="0">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="billing_price<? echo $row_count; ?>"  id="billing_price<? echo $row_count; ?>" class="span2" onkeydown="totalBillItem('<?php echo $row_count; ?>')" onkeyup="totalBillItem('<?php echo $row_count; ?>')" value="0">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="total<? echo $row_count; ?>" id="total<? echo $row_count; ?>" class="span2" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>

    <input type="hidden" name="prod_uuid<? echo $row_count; ?>" value="<? echo $dta['product_uuid']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_amount<? echo $row_count; ?>" value="<? echo $dta['product_amount']; ?>">
<?php
  $row_count++;
    endforeach;
?>
   <input type="hidden" name="row_ctr" value="<? echo $row_count; ?>">
</table>
<br />
Total:
<input type="text" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" class="span2" readonly>
```

How can I do it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/c4rjk/

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far, if you have done so!

Comment: @Nil'z: See edited post above.

Comment: SHow us your HTML or produce this in a FIDDLE

Comment: @MarsOne: I'll just edit it above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to see what's going on, but I do see a problem in this code:

```
while(rowcount != 0){
    var sub_total = parseFloat($("#total"+rowcount).val());
    rowcount--; 
}
```

You're simply resetting the sub_total on each loop, and it's actually going out of scope when you exit the while loop (don't know if that matters in Javascript).

Change this to the following:

```
var sub_total = 0;
while(rowcount != 0){
    sub_total += parseFloat($("#total"+rowcount).val());
    rowcount--; 
}
```

EDIT:

Here's a different way of counting the total.

Add a class name to the "total" row in html: (Replaced span2 for now, but you can change that later)

```
  <input type="text" class = "total" name="total<? echo $row_count; ?>" id="total<? echo $row_count; ?>" readonly>
```

And replace the while loop with this:

```
var total_element = document.getElementsByClassName('total');
var sub_total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < total_element.length; ++i) {
    var item = total_element[i];
    if (total_element[i].value) sub_total += parseFloat(total_element[i].value);
}
```

Do note that getElementsByClassName isn't supported in IE8 or before :(

Comment: It seems like you're using php's $rowcount as both an identifier and a total count of rows.  For instance, if the first row is changed, it'll get the data correctly, but only the first row will be counted and added since the while loop will only see a rowcount of 1.  Try splitting them by adding a $rowid parameter.

Comment: This is exactly what I need:  http://jsfiddle.net/c4rjk/
Only that mine is in a table.